# using .NET Regex.Replace() to replace expression more than once

Tags: c#, .net, regex, replace

I couldn't seem to find a match for this question so my apologies in advance if it's a duplicate.

Given the template: `<<FirstName>> << FirstName >>`

I want to replace both strings between the `'<<>>'`'s using a single regex that should match both.

The following code doesn't seem to work the way I'm expecting:

```
[Test]
public void ShouldReplaceMultiple()
{
  var pattern = "<<.*FirstName.*>>";
  var template = "<<FirstName>> <<FirstName>>";
  var replaceWith = "FOO";

  var regex = new Regex(pattern); 

  Assert.AreEqual("FOO FOO", regex.Replace(template, replaceWith));
}
```

The output of the test is as follows:

```
Expected string length 7 but was 3. Strings differ at index 3.
  Expected: "FOO FOO"
  But was:  "FOO"
  --------------^
```

I don't understand why both strings won't be replaced?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
string pattern = @"<<(?<=<<)\s*FirstName\s*(?=>>)>>";
var template = "<<FirstName>> <<FirstName>>";
var replaceWith = "FOO";

var regex = new Regex(pattern); 

Assert.AreEqual("FOO FOO", regex.Replace(template, replaceWith));
```

Answer (score 3):

Make it non-greedy using `.*?`

```
var pattern = "<<.*?FirstName.*?>>";
var template = "<<FirstName>> <<FirstName>>";
var replaceWith = "FOO";

var regex = new Regex(pattern); 

Console.WriteLine(regex.Replace(template, replaceWith));
```

**[Ideone Demo](http://ideone.com/0et7nj)**

If you want to deal only with `spaces` in between the `<<>>`, then this will suffice

```
<<\s*?FirstName\s*?>>
```

Comment: <<FirstName sdf>> is matched by your pattern.

Comment: @M.S.  as per OP :- `I want to replace both strings between the '<<>>''s using a single regex `..also OP is using `.*` in pattern